# How to set the camera in a precise position?

Tags: camera

I'm following a tutorial and the creator made the camera into this certain position that I can't seem to follow:

[image]

Comment: Please upload images using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: The creator probably held CTRL while dragging to snap the camera to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rotate the camera 90 degree along the Y-axis. To do so, select the camera, then hit <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then 90.

Answer (score 1):

If going with rotation exactly as in the screenshot then you can just [reset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#clear) rotation of the camera object. Reset location as well to make the camera staying in the center of the scene.

To do this, select camera, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for resetting rotation and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for scale.

[image]